# Angular: how to declare conditional Component on Routes

Tags: angular

I'm trying to declare a "dynamic" route component in angular.

This is my module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':machine', component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: (() => {
          return IsServerCondition ? MonitoringServerComponent : MonitoringClientComponent;
        })()
      },      
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MonitoringRoutingModule { }
```

I would like to change the component to be displayed based on the argument :machine of the parent path route.  How can I do it?

Comment: it depends on what is `IsServerCondition`. if it is static, then you can solve it with `matcher`, else, it is possible do do DummyComponent like  Some random IT boy advises, or you can put your 2 components on 2 "fake" routes, and on your current route you can declare a guard that will redirect to one or another fake route, without url change.

Comment: I'm going to adopt Some random IT boy suggestion, but I'll try even your fake routes idea. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you already know the predefined values of the parameter :machine you could use static routing to map to each component

In case you need to make a network request, you could certainly use a "dummy" component that makes the network request and later based on a response from the backend `*ngIf or *ngSwitch` to see which component to load.

template

```html
<app-client-component *ngIf="serverCondition$ | async; else server"></app-client-component>
<ng-template #server>
    <app-server-component></app-server-component>
</ng-template>
```

typescript

```js
@Component({…})
export class DummyComponent implements OnInit {

    serverCondition$ = this.actRoute.paramMap.pipe(
        // for direct comparison
        map(params => param.get('machine') === 'red')
        // or for a network request result
        switchMap(params => this.service.checkBackend(param.get('machine'))),
        map(response => response === 'red')
    );
    constructor(
        private actRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        private service: BackendService
    ) {}
}
```

Comment: Simply brilliant!  It is like a WPF Template Selector but in Angular style, I'm going to do it right now. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!